# How to show activity indicator while passing between view controller

Tags: swift, swift3, uistoryboardsegue, uiactivityindicatorview

Lets say I have 2 `ViewControllers`, in my MainViewController I have a button which performs a segue to SecondViewController. When button tapped, I'm saving some initial data to coreData, so it takes some time.

Here is the thing that I want to do;
While passing between ViewControllers, I want to show `ActivityIndicator`, but its starts after SecondViewController is opened. Could you help me? I'm new to Swift.

Here is the code I used in my MainVC:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "SecondViewController") {

            SwiftSpinner.show("Loading") // Act. indicator found on github

            willRunOnce() // Here Im saving data to CoreData

            SwiftSpinner.hide()
        }

    }
```

Comment: You must show spinner on button click and must hide it after `prepareForSegue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding code of `ActivityIndicator` in `prepare(for:sender:)` method you need to call it in the Button action and after that call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` method.

```
@IBAction func onBtnSkip(_ sender: UIButton) {

    SwiftSpinner.show("Loading") // Act. indicator found on github
    willRunOnce() // Here Im saving data to CoreData
    SwiftSpinner.hide()

    //Now performSegue 
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Will you show what is `willRunOnce()`, is it making any async call?

Comment: Not doing async call, is it relevant with that ?, probably :)

Comment: Yes if you are making any async or block inside  `willRunOnce()` then it will execute that block later first it will execute  `self.performSegue`.

Comment: what is the simplest method to add async call to get my problem solved

Comment: @EnesKaraosman You are misunderstanding, What I'm try to say is if your code contains any Async call inside `willRunOnce()`, then it will call `performSegue` before that, Can you show what is `willRunOnce()`. That will give more idea what you are trying.

Comment: solved my problem doing,  
 in willRunOnce() function, i was saving an object to core data in for loop and each cycle trying to saveContext, so changed it after for loop. I learned that i should not send request repeatedly to core data..
Also async call of course